# Reach neo4j-server over https on debian

Tags: https, neo4j, server

I have installed neo4j-v3.0.3 from neo4j-Debian-repository on Debian Jessie and enabled https-support in neo4j.conf.

I can reach the neo4j-browser over https://localhost:7473

but not 
with

https://server-ip:7473

There is no firewall installed, with v2.3.5 it worked.

Any hints would be apprecheated.

Answer (score 1):

Did you set

```
dbms.connector.https.address=0.0.0.0:7473
```

in `neo4j.conf`?

Comment: Yes, have uncommented this line.

Comment: what's the output on `netstat -atnp| grep LISTEN | grep 7473`?

Comment: The problem occurs even on the Mac-tar-gz-version. Obviously its not a Debian-package problem.

Comment: netstat -atnp| grep LISTEN | grep 7473
didnt work so i deleted the 'p'.


netstat -atn | grep LISTEN | grep 7473
tcp4       0      0  127.0.0.1.7473         *.*                    LISTEN

Comment: can you please doublecheck if `dbms.connector.https.address` really has a value of `0.0.0.0:7473`. The default line in stock neo4j.conf contains `localhost` instead. I've just verified that it does work.

Comment: Got it, havent seen localhost, thats it. default line had 0.0.0.0:7473 before and i didnt check that. sorry about that and thanks :-)